# INotifyPropertyChanged through layers of indirection

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, indirection

This may be an X-Y problem. Please don't hesitate to tell me if I'm completely off-base here.

First, a simplified example of the kind of situation I am thinking of.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XXXXXXX
{
    public class AbstractOperation : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public enum OpState { Init, Running, Aborted, Completed, Errored };
        OpState privateOperationState;
        public OpState OperationState
        {
            get => privateOperationState;
            private set
            {
                if(privateOperationState!=value)
                {
                    privateOperationState = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsRunning => OperationState == OpState.Running;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class BackgroundOperator
    {
        AbstractOperation whatever;

        public bool IsRunning => whatever.IsRunning;
        public AbstractOperation.OpState OperationState => whatever.OperationState;
    }

}
```

AbstractOperation is to be a base class representing some multi-step operation that takes significant time to perform. It will expose the status of it's operation through some properties.

BackgroundOperation is a class that will take an AbstractOperation and run it in a background thread, passing through some of the status properties. I want to be able to bind some UI element properties to these operations so that, for example, a certain control is disabled while the operation is running. I understand that the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is necessary for bindings like this to work.

If I implement the PropertyChange event on just one property like this, will the notification automatically cover other properties that refer to this property in their body? Does it work only within the class, or does it still work with another class that owns an instance of the notifying class? Do I need to do some special code to link the referring properties to the original property's notification? Or am I deep into X-Y land here and should implement some other way of binding UI controls to the status of my operation?

Answer (score 0):

> If I implement the PropertyChange event on just one property like this, will the notification automatically cover other properties that refer to this property in their body?

What happened when you tried it? Did you get property change notification for other properties?

> Does it work only within the class, or does it still work with another class that owns an instance of the notifying class?

It doesn't do that at all, so it won't do it in any other class.

Property change notification isn't magic. It just raises the event, setting the name value in the event args object to the one you passed in to the `OnPropertyChanged()` method (in this case, implicitly via the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute).

All that said, using properties like this isn't necessarily the best way to deal with disabling commands. You don't say what API you're actually using, but a common one that uses this sort of pattern is WPF. It uses `ICommand` bindings for commands. The `ICommand.CanExecute()` method should be used to indicate whether a command is valid at a given time. `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` should be raised when the value for that method changes. This is typically done by whatever code begins an operation or changes some state that would render the command invalid at that time. The same code would then change the `CanExecute()` state back to valid when it's done.

The exact mechanism for changing the command state and raising its event depends on how you implement the command. There are lots of examples out there, which you should review. See what works best for you.

If you are using some other API, it may or may not have a similar mechanism. It's not possible to know what the best answer along those lines would be, since that information is not available in your question.

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning, this is a WPF project. As far as testing goes, I am still learning how many of these events and interfaces work so I don't fully trust myself to either A) do the test properly or B) interpret the results correctly. It sounds like the property notifications are as limited as I feared they would be.

Comment: Being a WPF project, do you think the ICommand CanExecute is better? Can you link to a sample of how to implement it the way you are suggesting?

Comment: Also I should mention it's not just commands I want to enable/disable, but UI controls themselves. For example, when one of these operations is running I want a litstview I'm using to be greyed out (disbaled), then re-enabled once the operation finishes.

Comment: @Mark: _"do you think the ICommand CanExecute is better?"_ -- yes. _"Can you link to a sample of how to implement it the way you are suggesting?"_ -- not really. I don't have any first-hand knowledge of specific samples. A web search would be a good place for you to start. _"it's not just commands I want to enable/disable, but UI controls themselves"_ -- for controls that don't automatically do that (buttons, menu items, and the like do) you can subscribe to a command's `CanExecuteChanged` and handle enable/disable state changes manually.